# Animation in Android

Tags: android

I am having a default layout from which i have to inflate new layout..My code is here

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.mydeals_list);

     list_layout=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mydeals_list_layout);
```

If this condition satisfies i want new Layout how i can hide the R.layout.mydeals_list layout and make new layout Visible

```
if(Signin.login_flag){
     list_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) DbServerActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     final View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.slider, (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.slider_main_layout));
```

---------Place i want to display new layout ----------------

```
         Animation slideUpIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(DbServerActivity.this,R.anim.slide);
         slide_layout.startAnimation(slideUpIn);

      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you are after, your wording is a little strange to me.

However, you may find a ViewFlipper to your liking.

A ViewFlipper can let you swap between various Layouts.